# How do I change border color of Bootstrap forms input fields when flask wtforms throws error?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a Bootstrap form with `form-control` class. Using Flask wtforms when any error is caught in any of the input form fields. I want to change the border color for each of the fields using script tag inside the error for loop. But the border colors are not changing. Where am I going wrong?

Here is what I have tried :

```
<form name="adminreg" id="adminreg" action="/admin-reg" method="post" novalidate>
    {{ form.csrf_token() }}
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </span>
        </div>
        {{ form.name(class_="form-control", placeholder="Username")}}
    </div>

    <!-- changing the border color when error using jquery-->
    {% for error in form.name.errors %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".form-control").css("border-color", "red");
        </script>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution to this question. After the div tag ends we can use style tag to add styling to the html element on the go.

```
{% for error in form.name.errors %}
    <style>
          .form-control {border-color: red;}
    </style>
{% endfor %}
```

This will add red borders to all the form-control class fields in our form. To selectively add border you can give id to each form field element and target it separately.

Comment: Nice! Rather than looping through the list though, I suggest to check the presence of error in any of the form fields and render the style once where there is an error.

Comment: copy that, will keep this in mind!! you can edit the answer if you want to add something more